# Angular $http service not getting objects from .JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-promise

Here is my http service code:

```
app.controller('StoreController', ['$http', function($http){
    var store = this;
    store.products = [];
    $http.get('/store-products.json').then(function(data){
        store.products = data;
    });
}]);
```

And here is my JSON code:

```
[
    {
        "name": "...",
        "price": 20.00,
        "description": "...",
        "canPurchase": false,
        "images": [
            "...jpg",
            "...jpg",
            "...jpg"
        ],
        "reviews": []
    },
    {
        "name": "...",
        "price": 15.95,
        "description": "...",
        "canPurchase": true,
        "images": [],
        "reviews": []
    }
]
```

When I run the code on localhost server, it does not show my objects. There is also no errors in the console that show so I cannot see where I am going wrong. Can anyone see the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json data is wrapped at `response.data` of `$http.get`.

change to below code will solve the problem(also make sure your json file is at right location).

```
$http.get('/store-products.json').then(function(res){
    store.products = res.data;
});
```

**[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RnufjUAt8WfJT2H5T6wG?p=preview)**.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I'm learning angular at the moment and the way I coded the http service first is the way they advised to code it strangely..